# Update colum with existing value + newvalue

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone thnx in advance.I have a code like this

```
if ($option=="deny"){
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $money = $_POST["money"];
        $username=$_POST["username"];
        $myDb->connect();
        $queryz = "DELETE FROM payments WHERE id='$id'";
        mysql_query($queryz) or die(mysql_error());
        $queryb = "UPDATE yob_users SET money=[value] + '$money' WHERE username='$username'";
        mysql_query($queryb) or die(mysql_error()); $myDb->close();}
```

In Update query set new value of money with existing value + `$money` .
But

> UPDATE yob_users SET money=[value] + '$money' WHERE username='$username'

Doesn't work.

Comment: `[value]` that's MSSQL syntax, which should have thrown an error, which incidentally, haven't included what it was. See RC's comment.

Comment: `UPDATE yob_users SET money=money+...` most likely (BTW beware of SQL injection)

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be:

`$queryb = "UPDATE yob_users SET money = money + ".$money." WHERE username='".$username."'";`

You should use [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/mysqli) functions. `mysql_*` group of functions are now obsolete should not be used anymore.

And the change is pretty easy, update all your `mysql_` functions like `mysql_query()` with `mysqli_query()`. Almost all `mysql_` function has a corresponding `mysqli_` function with same name. Not getting into all the details about escaping input or binding for security, you should read up on how to make sure your app secure - especially if it's ecommerce driven.

Comment: MySQLi will protect you against SQL injection if you use bind variables, not simply use injected values in SQL statements

Comment: @MarkBaker - agreed. Also mysqli provides better debugging features (mysqli_debug()), also it lets you utilize almost all of the newer MySQL server functionalities, which MySQL does not always support. Further more, if PHP gets upgraded to a later version your code will simply break!

Comment: LOL - I got two downvotes for my answer without any explanation. Guess your comment made some people think I was wrong because I did not mention about using bind variables, @MarkBaker :)

Comment: @raidenace - sorry, that wasn't my intent, was just highlighting the fact after Adeel's comment

Comment: @MarkBaker - I know :) - and its a very good thing to point out, especially since the db manipulation seems to involve "money" - the OP needs to make sure that its as secure as possible. +1 to you. 

I just get frustrated at people who downvote and don't tell why, because if they do we get a chance to improve on our own answers and everyone benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryb = "UPDATE yob_users SET money='value' + ".$money."  WHERE username='".$username."'";
```

Comment: Please don't do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  Even as an example, use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the advice, but I think he wants just to run the query, after it runs well, someone can think about its security. There is an other website on here related to security and I am there. This is just for normal programming.

Comment: Your point regarding just answering the specific question is valid. However mentioning that security is discussed at other places isn't too helpful. Perhaps you could update your answer with a disclaimer that this is just an working query - but isn't production ready.